# How to enable sorting on an ItemTemplate column of checkboxes in the .aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

This is how I have it in the `.aspx` page:

```
<asp: TemplateField HeaderText="Hide/Show" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="HideShowChk" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("Hide_Show") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
<asp: TemplateField>
```

This is how the `TemplateField` is like in `Griview`. How do I enable sorting on this since the "Enable Sorting" checkbox in Visual Studio doesn't enable it for this column.

Note, I have absolutely no code in the code behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `SortExpression` property within the `TemplateField`

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hide/Show" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" SortExpression="Hide_Show">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="HideShowChk" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("Hide_Show") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
<asp:TemplateField>
```